# How do I set an initial value for one of my method in a class

Tags: python

I have a class named `knob` and one of my methods is `get_click(click)`. Right now when I call the method `get_click(click)` I have to specify a Integer value first in order for the code to execute like so `knob.get_click(5000)`. How would I design this portion so that if I don't specify an Integer value the `get_click(click)` would run would pass a default value and only change when I add an Integer parameter. I tried adding default values in the constructor, but the `get_click(click)` function kept asking for an argument.

```py
class knob:
    def __init__(self, click = "7000", rotateleft="50", rotateright="50"):
        self.click = click
        self.rotateleft = rotateleft 
        self.rotateright = rotateright 
    
    def get_click(click): 
        print("G4 "+ str(click) +"\r\n")

    def get_rotateleft(self):
        return self.rotateleft
    
    def get_rotateright(self):
        return self.rotateright
```

Comment: Did you mean: `def get_click(click=5000):`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def get_click(self, click=5000): # Set Default value for click
    print("G4 "+ str(click) +"\r\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that fixed my problem. Can I also ask why you included self as one of the arguments in the method? It seems that when I take out self, ie: def get_click(click=5000), the code works just fine and does not ask for an argument 'self'.

Comment: The first parameter of a method is always the instance itself and by convention it's called `self`.